# Get Azure AD custom domain list using graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are planning to add support for azure AD login using custom domain in our multi tenant application. How do I get list of custom domains added in azure AD using graph API? or is there any other way to get list of custom domains added in Azure AD?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Microsoft Graph API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains
```

This returns a collection of [domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/domain?view=graph-rest-1.0) objects.

Comment: Since then the API has changed. For people that are in search for this, the new documentation can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http